# Is it possible to send custom metrics to the DataDog server through the java agent?

Tags: java, datadog

We are running our spring boot java app with datadog java agent in kubernetes using this command:

java -javaagent:/dd-java-agent.jar -Ddd.profiling.enabled=false -jar /myapp.jar

We want to send custom metrics to datadog server through the java agent. Is it possible to send custom metrics using statsd protocol by connecting to the UDP port 8125 on localhost. Or do we have to connect to datadog server directly?

Thank you!